# What is wrong?JS --change font size with prompt

Tags: javascript, styles

**What is wrong?**

```js
function set_font_size() {
    var x;
    x=prompt("Insert font size");
    document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize=x;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Set font size" 
onclick="set_font_size()">
<p id="text">text</p>
```

Please help!

Comment: You need to tell _us_ what's wrong, not the other way round. How can someone help you if you don't tell them what the problem is?

Comment: Your code works fine, if I enter "50px" in the prompt box.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `unit`

```
document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = x+'px';
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5e53scf4/)

Comment: Why create a jsfiddle, when you can simply add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function set_font_size() {
    var x;
    x=prompt("Insert font size");
    document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize=x + "px";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Set font size" 
onclick="set_font_size()">
<p id="text">text</p>
```

You didn't specified type of value("px", "em"...)

```
document.getElementById("elem").style.fontSize = x+"px";
```